# Integral from 0 to infinity of $e^{-ax^b}$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I want to compute

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^b}\ dx$$

I am trying to use the Gamma Function in order to do this, but am running into difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the substitution $u = ax^b$. Does that yield a Gamma function integral?